# My Zend project is not working on localhost but working fine on web server

Tags: php, zend-framework

As mentioned in title i have a full project which is developed using Zend framework and which is also working fine on Web Server but it is not working on my local machine (means localhost). its showing Error

Strict Standards: Declaration of Aman_Controller_Plugin_CustomerDb::preDispatch() should be compatible with Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract::preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) in C:\xampp\htdocs\v2\salem\libraries\Aman\Controller\Plugin\CustomerDb.php on line 18

weather login functionality is working

please help me

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, it's weird it to be working on web server. Your server is probably not showing the error but it's surely happening.

Problem there is that you are implementing a method (preDispatch()) of the abstract class Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract and you are not doing it correctly. To implement a method of an abstract, it should accept the same number and type of arguments than its parent.

That is: Your controller (Aman_Controller_Plugin_CustomerDb::preDispatch()) has a method named preDispatch(), that method declaration should look **exactly** as:

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){
    /* Do stuff */
}
```

Comment: please tell me that what i do with method because i am not clear with answer so please provide suit able help